# Text-overflow not working in IE8+ for table columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I made a table, using bootstrap. I want to add text limitations. below is the html. The table and its limitations is working fine in chrome and firefox but now working in IE8+.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered dashboard-table">
  <thead style="background-color: #F8DAC2; border-bottom: 3px solid #CA6A15; font-size: 12px">
    <tr>
      <th>Entity</th>
      <th>Board Meeting/Other committees of the board</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Exceptional Items</th>
      <th>Issues</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
      <th>Respective Company's CEO/CFO's comment thereto</th>
      <th>Approve/Reject Remarks</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-justify"  style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #000;">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="#"> ABNL</a></th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>2 Jul 2015</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle-o" style="font-size: 20px; color: #007401"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th scope="row"><a href="#"> ABFNL</a></th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>2 Jul 2015</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times-circle-o" style="font-size: 20px; color: #CC0001"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><a href="#"> ABFNL</a></th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>2 Jul 2015</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times-circle-o" style="font-size: 20px; color: #CC0001"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the css class for the same I have made. the original bootstraps I haven't changed.

```
.dashboard-table tbody tr td{
    max-width: 200px ;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `width` instead of `max-width`?

Comment: Yes I have, its still not working.

Comment: Also, even if i remove all the bootstrap classes and only keep the `.dashboard-table tbody tr td` class, it still doesn't work in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not work like that I found the answer or its a work around I don't know but you need to add a div tag inside like below

```
 <tr>
          <td scope="row"><a href="#"> ABNL </a></td>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td style="width:70px">2 Jul 2015</td>
          <td><div>THIS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div></td>
          <td><div>THIS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div></td>
          <td><div>THIS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div></td>
          <td><div>THIS Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div></td>

          <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times-circle-o" style="font-size: 20px; color: #CC0001"></i><div style="width: 85%; float: right">Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor</div></td>
        </tr>

 <tr>
```